# Qt qml: Custom dialog not displayed on device, app crashes

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator, qml, customdialog

I'm trying to display a custom QML dialog on a real Android device (samsung galaxy express) but it is not working and it is also making the app to stop running. However, when I run the app on the Qt creator environment everything works fine!

The app output on Qt creator says something like this when the dialog has to be displayed:

> W/Adreno200-EGL(26802): : EGL_BAD_ACCESS
>   E/libEGL  (26802): eglMakeCurrent:534 error 3002 (EGL_BAD_ACCESS)
>   W/Qt      (26802): eglconvenience/qeglplatformcontext.cpp:128 (virtual bool QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent(QPlatformSurface*)): QEGLPlatformContext::makeCurrent: eglError: 3002, this: 0x58aebc90

The code of the custom dialog I made is as follows:

```
  Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
    width: 500
    height: 220
    flags: Qt.AlignCenter
    property Image imgGo1: imgGo1
    property Image imgGo2: imgGo2
    property Image imgDetectorH: imgDetectorH
    property Image imgDetectorV: imgDetectorV

    Image {
        source: "content/dialog_back.jpg"
        width: window.width
        height: window.height
    } ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

According to "[Anatomy of a Qt 5 for Android](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/07/23/anatomy-of-a-qt-5-for-android-application/)" Qt android does not support multiple activities. It cannot handle multiple surfaces (windows) either. You can use `Dialog` or `MessageDialog` for displaying a simple dialog. For changing the whole screen and creating a new view. You can use the `StackView` which has very nice features that help you to build mobile apps.